# is there a way to group outliers by factor and segment

Tags: r

I am trying to get the outlier grouped by factor and segment

```
df %>%
group_by(factor,segment) %>%
summarise(boxplot= list( boxplot.stats(column_name)$out),
out = list( c('out') ) ) %>%
unnest(stat, boxplot) %>%
spread(stat, boxplot)
```

Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :
invalid subscript type 'double'

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to see the outliers, outliers are identified as those points that fall 1.5*IQR past the first or third quartile.  You could define this quantity and then filter. This is what it would look like in the `diamonds` data, grouping outliers on `price` by `cut` and `color`:

```
out_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  mutate(hinge_spread = 1.5*IQR(price), 
         lwr = quantile(price, .25) - hinge_spread, 
         upr = quantile(price, .75) + hinge_spread) %>%
  filter(price > upr | price < lwr)
```

Comment: thanks alot Dave it is working now, however i am trying to loop over all columns of the dataframe and not a single one

Comment: What do you want the output to  look like?